# Terminal Javascript Timer Without New Line

Tags: javascript

I'm using terminal and i want to make a every time changed text without new line

here is my code

```
var c = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;
function timedCount() {
    term.pause();
    if (c == 100) {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
    else {
        term.echo(c);
        c = c + 1;
        t = setTimeout(function(){ timedCount() }, 100);
        t = setTimeout(function(){ timeClear() }, 900)
    }
}

function timeClear(){
    term.clear();
}

function startCount() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        timer_is_on = 1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on = 0;
}

timedCount();
```

I'm tryng to do every seconds add text without new line

example : `Hello + 1` , `Hello 2`

Comment: can you create a fiddle jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Where is `term` object defined? Also, it's not being passes as a parameter to the functions that actually you want to use it.